# Column Unkown With UPPER in HAVING clause for Column alias

Tags: mysql, alias, having, clause

I have a webapp that uses DataTables with server side processing. I have some SQL Queries that arbitrarily regroups data in columns, so I get queries like this:

```
SELECT case `column`
WHEN 'value1' then 'group1'
WHEN 'value2' then 'group1'
ELSE `column` END AS `column grouped`, SUM(`2010`)
GROUP BY `colonne grouped`
```

Now, I add some filtering based on user input, and I do like this:

```
SELECT case `column`
WHEN 'value1' then 'group1'
WHEN 'value2' then 'group1'
ELSE `column` END AS `column grouped`, SUM(`2010`)
GROUP BY `column grouped`
HAVING `column grouped` LIKE '%test%'
```

And it still work just fine, but my woes come when I try to make the whole thing case insentive, and so I do:

```
SELECT case `column`
WHEN 'value1' then 'group1'
WHEN 'value2' then 'group1'
ELSE `column` END AS `column grouped`, SUM(`2010`)
GROUP BY `colonne grouped`
HAVING UPPER(`column grouped`) LIKE '%test%'
```

And now I get "#1054 - Unknown column 'column grouped' in 'having clause'"

AS a workaround, I do something like this:

```
SELECT case `column`
WHEN 'value1' then 'group1'
WHEN 'value2' then 'group1'
ELSE `column` END AS `column grouped` , SUM(`2010`)
GROUP BY `colonne grouped`
HAVING UPPER(case `column`
WHEN 'value1' then 'group1'
WHEN 'value2' then 'group1'
ELSE `column` END) LIKE '%test%'
```

But this is not really convenient. Anyone knows why I'm not able to use UPPER with custom alias ?

I am using MySQL 5.5 by the way.

Comment: have you tried putting the UPPER on the column and not the CASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) you cannot use functions in the `HAVING` clause:

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in
>   the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However,
>   MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to
>   refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as
>   well.

You're restricted to columns you've already retrieved. I don't know if there's a technical reason behind but that's what the SQL standard mandates.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense, although the error is confusing. Now hte funny part is that if I use HAVING UPPER(CASE xxx WHEN yy then zz) it totally works.

Comment: Hmmm... If that works, then my answer is wrong, isn't it? :-?

Answer (score 0):

try to make `UPPER` in `WHERE` clause

```
      SELECT case `column`
     WHEN 'value1' then 'group1'
     WHEN 'value2' then 'group1'
     ELSE `column` END AS `column grouped`, SUM(`2010`)
     WHERE UPPER(`column grouped`) LIKE '%test%'
     GROUP BY `colonne grouped`
```

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to use having when using group by, but it looks like I just need it for columns I use a mathematical function with... Thanks !

Comment: Hello, That doesn't help since the column `colonne grouped` doesn't actually exist.

Comment: u funny :) , u have used `colonne grouped` in your example , but of course you can change it to your column grouped , i just answered as you wrote ,